# PFLogInViewControllerDelegate functions not called

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, pfuser, parseui

When using `PFLogInViewController` (or a subclass of it), it looks like none of the functions inside `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` are ever called. Eventhough the main ViewController declares to conform to the `PFLogInViewControllerDelegate` protocol and the delegate for the `PFLogInViewController` object is set.

Is there something else to do ?

Here is the relevant code, though I don't think it will bring more than what is written above:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {
    var loginVC:PFLogInViewController!
    ....
    func someFunc() {
        if (loginVC == nil) {
            loginVC = PFLogInViewController()
            loginVC.delegate = self
        }

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
    }
    ....
    // MARK: - PFLogInViewControllerDelegate

    // Sent to the delegate to determine whether the log in request should be submitted to the server.
    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController,
                             shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username:String,
                             password: String) -> Bool {
        print(#function) // THIS IS NEVER CALLED!!!

        return true
    }


    // Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is logged in.
    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) {
        print(#function) // THIS IS NEVER CALLED!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: When does someFunc()  Called?

Comment: someFunc() is called at some point and the PFLogInViewController is created. That is not the issue. The question is "Why the functions inside PFLogInViewControllerDelegate are never called?"

Comment: Because you pushed the loginVC to navigationController after assigning the delegate object...remove it and try again

Comment: Why would this be a problem? If I replace "self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)" by "self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)", the problem is exactly the same. What else can I do?
What do you mean by "remove it and try again"?

Comment: can you give the code of PFLogInViewController at in your question?

Comment: No PFLogInViewController is not mine. It is part of Parse, you can see on the Internet (available on GitHub).